# Adding thumbnail to aw blog in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Just in need of some assistance. I have downloaded aw blog for magento 1.7 and it is pulling (x) amount of articles in the home page.

What i would like to do is have the ability for admin to attach a thumbnail per article and pull this thumbnail in the home page.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Magento community edition 1.7
Aw_blog (latest version)

Comment: http://forum.aheadworks.com/featured-image-t3821.html